# Zend framework 2.3 translate form

Tags: php, zend-framework2, translation

I have a problem with translating form (labels).
After searching hours on the internet, I can't find a decent explanation how it should be done.

Anybody who can give me a help here?

I'm using the formCollection($form) as written in the ZF2.3 manual

add.phtml

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('album', array('action' => 'add')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form); 
echo $this->formCollection($form);
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

AlbumForm.php

```
 namespace Album\Form;

 use Zend\Form\Form;
 use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;

 class AlbumForm extends Form
 {
     public function __construct($name = null)
     {
         // we want to ignore the name passed
         parent::__construct('album');

         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'id',
             'type' => 'Hidden',
         ));

         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'title',
             'type' => 'Text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => $this->getTranslator()->translate('Name'), //'Naam',
             ),
         ));

         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'artist',
             'type' => 'Text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Code: ',
             ),
         ));

         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'submit',
             'type' => 'Submit',
             'attributes' => array(
                 'value' => 'Go',
                 'id' => 'submitbutton',
             ),
         ));
     }
 }
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Album\Form\AlbumForm::getTranslator() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/demo/module/Album/src/Album/Form/AlbumForm.php on line 24
```

Comment: Where in the docs does it say to use getTranslator on the Form class? There's no getTranslator method in Zend/Form/Form so if you've not added one to Album/Form then obviously it's not going to work. I'm curious as to what you read in the docs. It probably meant getTranslator is implemented elsewhere.

Comment: You'll need to inject the translator service if you want to do this within the form. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923378/zf2-equivalent-of-getservicelocator-in-zend-form

Comment: @bcmcfc: It's nowhere written in the manual.
I've been searching on the internet and stackoverflow for information and solutions. I found this information somewhere to try, but unsuccesfull.
So that's where I ended.

Comment: @cptnk: thanks for the link! I will have look here and see if this can help me.

Answer (score 2):

The form has no knowledge of a translator by default. What you can do, is make it explicit and inject a translator. Therefore, define a factory for your form:

```php
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Album\Form\AlbumForm' => 'Album\Factory\AlbumFormFactory',
    ],
],
```

Now you can create a factory for this form:

```php
namespace Album\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

use Album\Form\AlbumForm;

class AlbumFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
    {
        $translator = $this->get('MvcTranslator');
        $form       = new AlbumForm($translator);

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Now, finalize your form class:

```php
namespace Album\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface;

class AlbumForm extends Form
{
    protected $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;

        parent::__construct('album');

        // here your methods
    }

    protected function getTranslator()
    {
        return $this->translator;
    }
}
```